# Can't get to work onGenericMotionEvent in InputMethodService

Tags: android, service, motionevent

I've launched InputMethodService and activating it in settings, onCreate works - it return my string, but onGenericMotionEvent do nothing - it should send string to companion object when app resumed. Have no idea why it not working. Hope somebody can help me.

```
package com.pg.inputservice

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.provider.Settings

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var myTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //set permission
        var intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS)
        startActivity(intent)

        //launch service
        val service = Intent(this, IMService::class.java)
        startService(service)

        myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textMy)

        myTextView.text = "onCreateMain"

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        myTextView.text = IMService.test + " onResume"

        super.onResume()
    }

}
```

```
package com.pg.inputservice

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService
import android.view.MotionEvent

class IMService: InputMethodService() {
    companion object {
        var test: String = "initialisation"
    }

    override fun onCreate(){
        test = "onCreate"
    }

    override fun onGenericMotionEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        test = "onGenericMotionEvent"

        return true
    }
}
```